# render html file as html from php controller

Tags: php, html, render

UPDATED:

can someone explain why the first method displays as plain text but the second method displays as html?  I'm trying to display the file contents as html.

```
    <?php
echo getcwd() . '<br>';
```

METHOD 1

```
$body = file_get_contents('wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-child/views/html/email-footer.html');
echo $body;
```

METHOD 2

```
$body = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
   <head>
       <style>
           div{
               font-size:5vw!important;
              }
         #img1{
               width:100%!important;
              }
       </style>
</head>
<body lang=EN-US>
   <div style="text-align:center;margin:0 auto;font-size:16px">
      <!-- <img id="img1" style="width:70%;" src="cid:swag-logo">-->
       <p> Hi, <br><br> Thank you for your interest in Sustainable Weston
           Action Group. If you would like to sign up for our quarterly
           newsletter or have specific areas of interest/expertise that you
           would like to share,please complete  
           <a href=" https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/get-involved/" >our 
           Get Involved form</a> This information is for Sustainable Weston
           Action Group use only - we will not share your information with any 
           other parties.<br><br><br>Sustainable Weston Action Group</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>';

echo $body; 

?>
```

Comment: just lucky I guess.  Don't do much with php, do you have an answer or reference?

Comment: Does the `email-footer.html` file have HTML tags or is it just plain text?

Comment: It has tags but I just rediscovered htmlspecialchars and that fixed the problem